# Browser Crashes when uploading large files even after slicing on XMLHttpRequest (JavaScript/ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, filereader

I've been trying to find a clear answer on this for a while now, since some have only been for big CSV files for example.

The following code works perfectly for smaller files, whenever size exceeds 100 MB, upload process takes a big chunk of memory apparently.

I'm already slicing the files into smaller chunks as well, however apparently the initial reading of the file is causing this issue.

**Question: How should I change the following code to prevent the crashes to happen?**

```js
 axios.post(`/URL_GOES_HERE`, {
          name: file.name,
          size: file.size,
          md5,
          extension: file.type.split('/')[1]
        })
        .then((response) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = (e) => {
         
            const { chunks, type, status } = response.data;
            if (status === 'uploading') {
              let start = 0;
              chunks.forEach(async ({ materialId, size, index }) => {
                window.file0 = file;
                const buf = reader.result.slice(start, start + size);
                const arrayBuf = new Uint8Array(buf);
                start = start + size;
                const url = `URL_FOR_EACH_CHUNK`;

                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('PUT', url, false);
                xhr.setRequestHeader(
                  'Content-Type',
                  'application/octet-stream'
                );
                xhr.setRequestHeader(
                  'Authorization',
                  `Bearer TOKEN_GOES_HERE`
                );
                xhr.send(arrayBuf);
              });
            }
          };
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad way to upload files by slicing and reading the data.
just send the file as it's without reading the content

```js
const res = await fetch('URL_GOES_HERE', {
  method: 'post',
  body: file
})
await res.text()
```

if you really need to upload them partially with chunks then just slice the blob and upload that without sending arraybuffer

```js
chunk_to_send = file.slice(start, end)
xhr.send(chunk_to_send)
```

Browser will be able to pipe the data as a stream and upload them without any memory concern